# Counter exemple of a statement for a measurable sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions, sequence-of-function

In a former exam there was a multiple choice question about statements asking which one was true and the other 3 were wrong.

The following statement was said to be false but i can't understand why or find any counter-examples for which this statement is false. If anyone could help.

if $\{ f_n : R \rightarrow [-1,1] \} $ a sequence of measurable functions with $f_1 \leq f_2 \leq \cdots$ and $f_n$ converges pointwise to an absolutely integrable function $f$, then
$lim_{n -> \infty} \int_{R} f_n(x)dx = \int_R f(x)dx$.

Answer (score 4):

If they are not integrable you can have a simple counter example of

$$ f_n=-1+\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,n)} \quad \text{and} \quad f(x)=0. $$

You can see that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f=0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n= \int_{n}^\infty-1 dx=-\infty$. By the Beppo-Levi monotone convergence theorem, the counter example must be somehow negative. I also think that linearity of the integral and said theorem, must mean that the counter example comes from non-integrable functions.

Comment: Nice. Although the functions are bounded from below, the lower bound is not integrable (which I overlooked in my answer), which is why the monotone convergence theorem fails.